# Website Video Playback - Safari works but all other browsers do not

Tags: javascript, html, css, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hello Stack community,

I am currently working on an issue with videos not playing back appropriately on my personal website.  To best give an example I will just link to my site: rickyspringer.com. I am a student trying to use this as a project and have been tirelessly trying to figure this out.

The videos are hosted in AWS S3 - I have tried multiple formats.  I have tried using Movie Edit Pro on Mac with different formats.  MP4 and MOV.  Some of the attempts I've made the video would go straight to a download prompt, others would pop up and just show the audio.  It leads me to believe that it has something to do with the browsers but I can't put my finger on what it is.

The theme I purchased online because I am still learning.  So I have been editing it as I go to fit my needs.

Thank you community!

Comment: couldn't find any video on your website!